# If every metric on a set X is equivalent to the discrete metric then can we say X is a finite set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I know the result and the proof of the statement that

*If X is a finite set then any two metrics are equivalent and every metric on X is equivalent to the discrete metric on X.*

But I don't know whether the above result characterize finite sets?

Comment: Yes, it does. The conditions imply that every point admits a ball containing only the point itself. If you have infinitely many points, you can construct metrics which do not have this property.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Assuming (a weak form of) the axiom of choice**, yes, this is true.

Specifically, from the axiom of choice it follows that if $X$ is infinite then there is an injection $f:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow X$ (of course this $f$ isn't unique in any sense). Consequently, assuming choice we have that every infinite set can be equipped with a metric so that it has a subspace isometric to $\mathbb{Q}$.

In a bit more detail, given such an $f$, we can define a non-discrete metric $d$ on $X$ as follows:

- If $a\not\in ran(f)$ then, for every $b\in X$ other than $a$ itself, we set $d(a,b)=d(b,a)=2$.
- Meanwhile, for $m,n\in\mathbb{Q}$ we set $d(f(m),f(n))=\min\{\vert m-n\vert, 1\}$.

Basically, $(X,d)$ looks like a "trunacted" copy of $\mathbb{Q}$ with a bunch of discrete points scattered around it, and is certainly not discrete!

*(Note that this doesn't actually get a metric on $X$ with a subspace isometric to $\mathbb{Q}$; getting that is a good exercise.)*

---

However, if we **don't** assume the axiom of choice, things can be weirder: it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ (= set theory without choice) that there are infinite sets which cannot be partitioned into two infinite subsets. Such sets, called **amorphous** sets, cannot support a non-discrete metric; this is a good exercise.